# Change connection string of access database in visual studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Ok so, basically i want to connect an access database (.mdb file) to my project. Now yes i have indeed connected it through the "data origin" wizard but the problem is that when i transfer the exe AND the database to another pc, it doesn't find it (obviously).

```
Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Dim txtconnesione As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & appPath & "\Magazzino.mdb"
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TableMagazzinoBindingSource.DataSource = txtconnesione
        Me.TableMagazzinoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MagazzinoDataSet.TableMagazzino)

    End Sub
```

appPath is basically where the program gets started.
With this code it actually shows me the whole grid but it's empty, just like this:
[image]

i didn't used a connection string and i didn't copy it in the project (sorry for bad english, if you don't understand i'll try to explain better)

Comment: What is this: `Me.TableMagazzinoBindingSource.DataSource = txtconnesione`? When are you setting the DataSource of the grid? What kind of application is this? Where is the database located when you deploy?

Comment: _i didn't used a connection string_  But you did.  txtconnesione hold the connection string.  Aside, the fact that it didn't error (or perhaps it did and you've neglected that) suggests that it's found and connected to the DB, are you sure that it actually has data in it after being copied to the other PC?

Comment: @Jimi `Me.TableMagazzinoBindingSource.DataSource = txtconnesione` is a "test" of mine where txtconnessione is a string that contains the path where the exe is executed and the name of the database. _When are you setting the DataSource of the grid?_ please, can you explain better?

Comment: @Hursey  yes i checked and there is indeed data in it. and about the connection string: i "coded" the connection string (txtconnesione) so that it  is a string that contains the path where the exe is executed and the name of the database.  sorry if you can't understand my poor english

Comment: `TableMagazzinoBindingSource` looks like it's a BindingSource and you're setting its Datasource property to a string. It should be probably set to `MagazzinoDataSet.TableMagazzino`. The connection string is set to a OleDb / Sql Connection object or DataAdapter